Non nested loop to find mode in Java
I got an assignment that my professor has given me the code but I have to fill the answers in the assigned line to complete the code
I got with the fixed array in my problem
but when I rearrange position of the numbers in my array
My algorithm doesn’t work
here’s my code:
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3};
    int maxCnt = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int mem = arr[0];
    int cur = arr[0];
    int curCnt = 1;//you can modify this line with any value but it has to be curCnt =
    int mode = arr[0];
    
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<arr.length;i++) {
        cur = arr[i];
        if(cur == mem) {
            curCnt++;
        }
        else {
            if(curCnt > maxCnt) {
                mode = mem;
                maxCnt = curCnt;
            }
            /*mem = cur; you can modify in these two lines
            curCnt = 1;*/
        }
    }
    if(curCnt > maxCnt/*you can modify in this block*/) {
        mode = mem;
        maxCnt = curCnt;
    }
    System.out.printf("mode = %d%nfreq = %d", mode, maxCnt);
  }
}

The answers have to be filled in where I commented in the code

Please explain (with examples) what this code is supposed to do.

i want to print out the number which is mode and how often it appears in the array

If you run this with a debugger, it should become clear what the problem is.

How do I ask and answer homework questions?

I got with the fixed array in my problem but when I rearrange position of the numbers in my array My algorithm doesn’t work That's because your algorithm assumes that the array is sorted.

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3};
    int maxCnt = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int mem = arr[0];
    int cur = arr[0];
    int curCnt = 1;
    int mode = arr[0];
    for(int i=1;i<arr.length;i++) {
        cur = arr[i];
        if(cur == mem) {
            curCnt++;
        }
        else {
            if(curCnt > maxCnt) {
                mode = mem;
                maxCnt = curCnt;
            }
            // uncomment this lines it will work fine 
            mem = cur; 
            curCnt = 1;
        }
    }
    if(curCnt > maxCnt) {
        mode = mem;
        maxCnt = curCnt;
    }
    System.out.printf("mode = %d%nfreq = %d", mode, maxCnt);
  }
}

The output produced is :- 
mode = 3
freq = 4


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
